# Refreshing list on RecyclerView

Tags: android

I am fairly new in android programming.
I am having two cases where I am unable to get the list updated.

**FIRST**

Here is my Activity (QuestionList Activity).

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ques_list);
....


    quesList=quesDB.getQues(); //getting arraylist from database
    qAdapter = new QuesList_Adaptor(quesList, this, this);
    rv_qlist.setAdapter(qAdapter);
    qAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

On other activity, taking user input which updates the database (thus also updates quesList above).

```
 public void save (View view)
  {
    String ques = et_ques.getText().toString();
    String optionA = et_optA.getText().toString();
    String optionB = et_optB.getText().toString();
    String optionC = et_optC.getText().toString();
    String optionD = et_optD.getText().toString();
    String ans = et_ans.getText().toString();

    QuesDB qd = new QuesDB(this);
    boolean b = qd.addQues(ques, optionA, optionB, optionC, optionD, ans);
    if (b)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Question Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  *//so... I have to notify adapter here right? than, what's the way here to reference adaptor and use notifyDataSetChanged*
    finish();
```

**SECOND CASE**
Setting up Multi-delete on recyclerview. Data is getting deleted but trouble in refreshing the list.
Please take a look into the code, I mentioned there using comments.

On Activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
..

StoreNotesDB sdb = new StoreNotesDB(this);
noteslist= sdb.getStoreNotes(); //storing from database to array

mAdapter = new AdaptorNotes(this,noteslist, this);
rv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

}

```
@Override
public void OnLongClick() {
    fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    inActionMode = true;

    actionMode = this.startActionMode(new ContextualCallback());
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}

@Override
public void OnClick(AdaptorNotes.MyViewHolder holder, int pos) {
    if (holder.chk_notes.isChecked())
    {
        selected_list.add(noteslist.get(pos));

        //counter = counter + 1;

    }
    else
    {
        selected_list.remove(noteslist.get(pos));
        //counter = counter - 1;
    }

}


class ContextualCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {

        actionMode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.notescontextual_menu,     menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_delete:
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"delete",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                if (selected_list.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(NotesListViewActivity.this, "No item is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                else{
                     //loop for deleting item from database of the   selected list
                    for (MyStoreNotes myStoreNotes: selected_list)
                     {
                        String x = String.valueOf(myStoreNotes.getSl());
                        int y = storeNotesDB.deleteRow(x);
                     }

                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // it doesn't work

                    inActionMode = false;
                    selected_list.clear();
                    Toast.makeText(NotesListViewActivity.this, "Selected List Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    actionMode.finish();

                }
        }
        return false;
    }......
```

.....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're trying to refresh the data on each load of the activity, or if you are using a different method to refresh your data.

If you want to reload the data each time the recyclerview activity is shown, then you need to call...

```
quesList.clear();
```

after declaring the list, and before getting the data. That ensures that you are populating your recyclerview with the latest data from your database.

If this is not what you're asking, please explain what your app is currently doing vs what you want it to do.

Comment: In FIRST case. What I simply want is- while being on recycler view list when the data is added (question) using fab, which will move user to an another activity (for user to input) And when saved that should be immediately reflected on the list.  Now please take a look on code you will easily get the scenario